# How to stash working tree, update the local branch and merge the both modified

Tags: git, merge

What is the best way to stash working tree, update the local branch and then merge the both files modified either on local and on remote branch?

I'm doing as following:

- First, I `git stash`, the shortcut for `git stash save` and save my working tree
- Then I `git pull`, to update my local branch.
- Since my branch is updated, I use `git stash pop` to remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top of the current working tree state.

This isn't that bad, altough the merge part isn't the best. I just want to merge the changes, if possible with mergetool. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just commit and rebase?

```
git commit -a
git pull --rebase
*fix merge conflicts*
```

Then if you want to append to that commit you can do

```
git commit -a --amend
```

Then if you want to uncommit the commit you just made, but still save your changes, do a soft reset:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Comment: In specific days, not near the deadline :P, there are much commits to remote branches, and sometimes I need some updated funcionalities.